# How to enable scroll-to-div on click in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to add a scroll-to-div feature to my React App. Unfortunately due to the structure of my React app, I am unable to pass refs as props correctly. This is prohibiting me from using `ref.current.scrollIntoView()`.

My current code structure is as follows:

```
<Navbar />
    <Home />
    <About />
    <Courses />
    <Gallery />
    <Contact />
    <Careers />
<Divider />
<Footer />
```

I have tried creating ref's for each of the inner components (Home, About, Courses, ...) and passing them to Navbar and then calling the `scrollIntoView` function but it's logging as warning to the console and asking me to use `forwardRef` instead (which I've tried but it had no effect and did not remove the error).

How can I make it so that when I click links on the NavBar, the app scrolls down to the respective Components ?

Comment: You could try some mix of [`findDOMNode`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/findDOMNode).

Comment: Can you show how you implemented `forwardRef`? It's very unlikely something with `forwardRef` itself is wrong, if so you would need to open an issue on the React repo.

Comment: You could give each of those sections an id, and then pass that ID into a function that simply navigates to that id (e.g: /#courses). The browser scrolls there automatically.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "enable scroll-to-div on click"? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried and what issues are you facing? We can't address issues in code we can't see very well so please [edit] to include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, and provide more specific details about any issues or what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. I did find a solution to my problem and I have answered my own question. Also I have updated the question to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The solution was to pass the refs directly to the Navbar.

Then, in each of the components, I used forwardRef to receive a ref and then link the ref received, to the component. Code example:

### Project structure:

```
App.jsx
  <Navbar />
  <Home />
  <About />
  <Footer />
```

As you can see, the Navbar and Home component's are sibling components.

##### App.jsx:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const homeRef = useRef(null);
  const aboutRef = useRef(null);
  const refList = [homeRef, aboutRef];

    return (
    <>
      <Navbar refList={refList} />

      <Home ref={homeRef} />
      <About ref={aboutRef} />

    </>
  );
```

##### Navbar.jsx

```
export default Navbar({homeRef, aboutRef}) {
  return(
    <div>
      <Link className="nav-link" ref={ref} onClick={() => ref.current.scrollIntoView(scrollOpts)}>
        Home
      <Link />
    </div>
)}
```

##### Home.jsx

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const Home = forwardRef(({}, ref) => {
  return (
    <div className="main" ref={ref}>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  );
});

export default Home;
```